# Including Eigen in my project redefines the standard int to Eigen::DenseIndex - how to use the normal ints?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a vector to input some data from a .txt file, but I get the error:

```
no operator ">>" matches these operands

operand types are: std::ifstream >> std::vector<Eigen::DenseIndex, std::allocator<Eigen::DenseIndex>>
```

My code is:

```
dataIn.open("data.txt");
vector<int> hnew;
dataIn >> hnew;
dataIn.close();
```

data.txt is just a long vector of space separated ints. What can I do?

Comment: parse the file and build the vector manually?

Comment: Disregarding my original question then, how would I create a `vector<int>` where the data type is actually the standard c++ int, and not some redefinition made by Eigen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eigen::DenseIndex is just a type alias for int. It's not the problem here.

The compiler is warning you don't have an overload

```
template <typename T, typename A>
std::istream & operator >>(std::istream &, std::vector<T. A> &)
```

There isn't one provided by default. You can use [istream_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) to construct your hnew like this:

```
dataIn.open("data.txt");
vector<int> hnew(istream_iterator<int>(dataIn), istream_iterator<int>());
```

Comment: Thank you. Today I learned about type alias. However, I get an error at both of the `istream_iterator` using what you wrote: "argument list for class template "std::istream_iterator" is missing". 
I have #include <iterator>

Comment: Sorry, my first version was missing the `<int>` from `istream_iterator<int>`, fixed now